# How do you try the new hangouts?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts, google-hangouts-chat

This is the only thing I can see when I open google chat: [image: My Google Chat]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

By "the new Hangouts" I think that you mean Google Chat (formerly Google Hangouts Chat). It will be available for everyone the next year. In the mean time you could try it sign up to one of the offerings of Google Workspace.

Reference

- [The latest on Google Hangouts and the upgrade to Google Chat](https://blog.google/products/workspace/latest-google-hangouts-and-upgrade-google-chat/)